# Why does this C programm crash?

Tags: c, crash

I have written the following code, however I get a crash (without warnings or errors) and do not know the cause:

```
const int N = 1000;

int main(){   
    int *pI = calloc(N,sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        *(pI++) = (i+1);
    }
    free(pI);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am thankful for any advice!

Comment: Hint: when your program crashes, look into using a debugger. Or at least: put up print statements that tell you **where** exactly you crash.

Comment: You modify `pI`, so you can't call `free(pI)`, since it's no longer a pointer to a valid allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not releasing the original pointer received from `calloc()`:

```
 free(pI);
```

You have been modifying the value contained in this pointer:

```
*(pI++) = (i+1);
```

Do instead:

```
int *p = calloc(N,sizeof(int));
int *pI = p;
// ...
free(p);
```

That is, save the value returned from `calloc()` and then pass it to `free()` when you don't need the allocated memory anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for your alternative solution!